# Intellij does not ignore tests that are with @DoNotDiscover annotated

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

When I run the test from a package in Intellij ('package' -> Run -> ScalaTests in 'package')

Tests that are marked with `@DoNotDiscover` were run as well.

There is an issue reported ([youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9174)), but no workaround suggested nor a fix promised.

Is there a way to make this work?